# Referring to Speech

Tags: nouns

What is the difference between figure of speech and a metaphor? Is there not another side to this or is this the same term for both? 
For instance:

> **Noun: metaphor
>   |'me-tu,for|**
>   A figure of speech in which an expression is used to refer to something that it does not literally denote in order to suggest a similarity.

Answer (score 1):

A [figure of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech) is an overarching category that contains metaphor, simile, idiom, irony, hyperbole, and puns, to name only a few.

A metaphor has a more particular definition, as you cite: a figure of speech that plays with, or suggests similarity.